# how to use aggregate pipeline to fetch array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have 3 collections Schools,departments,books in mongodb
so I want to use aggregate function in nodejs to query school document and fetch corresponding department details for each school and also get book details from corresponding department document. below are more details:

1. Schools collection

```
{
  _id: "643fa7c76fd3bb2e2990b6c2",
  schools: [
    {
      id: "d8908bf22",
      name: "ab",
      url: "http:ab.com"
    },
    {
      id: "b6bcf",
      name: "cd",
      url: "http:cd.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. departments collection

```
[
  {
    _id: "643fb22e7c5ea747261d8400",
    name: "ab",
    value: {
      school: {
        name: "ab",
        id: "a6952a86-97ae-4de7-ad46-f7703681cb4a"
      },
      departments: [
        {
          id: "1faa82d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
          name: "ab1/ab1:dummy.json"
        },
        {
          id: "2faaq2d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
          name: "ab2/ab2:dummy.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    _id: "643fb22e7c5ea747261d8401",
    name: "cd",
    value: {
      school: {
        name: "cd",
        id: "c6952a86-97ae-4de7-ad46-f7703681cb4a"
      },
      departments: [
        {
          id: "cfaa82d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
          name: "cd1/cd1:dummy.json"
        },
        {
          id: "cfaaq2d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
          name: "cd2/cd2:dummy.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

3. books collection

```
[
  {
    departmentId: "1faa82d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
    value: {
      booksInfo: [
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "abcd",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "abcd2",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    departmentId: "2faaq2d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
    value: {
      booksInfo: [
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "abcd",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    departmentId: "2faaq2d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
    value: {
      booksInfo: [
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "xyz1",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "abcd1",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    departmentId: "cfaaq2d4-a618-4985-9840-03020b05a429",
    value: {
      booksInfo: [
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "xyz1",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "abcd1",
            "bookInfo": {
              "available": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I tried below code but i am getting result correctly for department details for each school but not getting result for books for corresponding department.
I need book details for each department of each school.

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $unwind: "$value.schools"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "departments",
      localField: "value.schools.name",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "departmentDetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$departmentDetails.value.departments"// this line not working
  }  
]
```

updated:
expected output is:

```
[
  school: {
      name:"ab"
      url:"http:ab.com"
      departments:[
        {
          "departmentId": "a6952a86-97ae-4de7-ad46-f7703681cb4a",
          "books":[{
                bookName:"abcd"
                available:"true"
               },
                {
                bookName:"abcd1"
                available:"false"
               }
 
         }

     ]
},
{
 //similar for other school
}
]
```

Can anyone please help
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the expected output as well

Comment: @CharchitKapoor, updated the expected output

Comment: In the last stage in Pipeline, you are required to run the unwind stage in two parts. First unwind departmentDetails, and then unwind the department part.